# Struggle with the Interface Builder to setup my App-Layouts

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview

The main problem is between switching 3.5" and 4" There are 2 pics they show exactly what my problem is.

[image: pic1]

---

[image: pic2]

You see at the second picture the UIImageView shrink a bit. This is not what I want. The better look is if the textView will scale down and maybe if the content is to big get scrollable.

```
How can i solve this? Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Plz! have a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) article, well written about **AutoLayout**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you have a look at this link.
[tutorial explaining autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

From what i can understand from the images, you should fix the imageview's height 
and edit the height of the the textview so that it have values less than of its current height
inorder to do so you can click the height constraint click the gear picture and edit it

Comment: I got that. Thanks for your hint